# log4j rollingfile appender not backing up daily file

Tags: playframework, log4j

This is my config for log4j.properties

```
log4j.rootLogger=ERROR, Rolling

log4j.logger.play=INFO

# Rolling files
log4j.appender.Rolling=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.Rolling.File=${application.path}/Temp/logs/application.log
log4j.appender.Rolling.MaxFileSize=1MB
log4j.appender.Rolling.MaxBackupIndex=100
log4j.appender.Rolling.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.Rolling.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{ABSOLUTE} %-5p ~ %m%n
```

My logs do not grow more than 1mb, however i do not find dailylogs even though i have set `MaxBackupIndex=100`

I searched the entire machine for `App*.log` but found only 1 for the current date.

Is there a setting I am missing?

Answer (score 0):

I think you must use the `DailyRollingFileAppender`(http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/DailyRollingFileAppender.html) here:

```
log4j.appender.Rolling=org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender
```

Or, as mentioned there in the Javadoc, the extras: http://logging.apache.org/log4j/companions/extras/